# Why email Giants like Gmail does not allows to upload the image from local box?

Tags: gmail, yahoo, email-signature

I want to to upload the image in gmail signature from my local box but it does not allow that. For this image should be present on public webserver.  I am not able to think what is the reason behind it? If image can be inserted in signature from public webserver why not from local box?

Second quetion if any text file can be sent from local box to server side why image can't be?

I need to work on similar kind of functionality. Just wanted to ensure what is the reason behind it so that i can  also keep that fact in mind? If it is not the right forum to have this kind of exchange, please let me know is there any related forum  on stack exchange regarding the same?

Answer (score 3):

One obvious thing comes into my mind: the signature images are linked and not attached, so they need to be present on a public URL. They could of course let you upload and host it somewhere, but it's understandable that introducing such service alongside existing image sharing is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks Dain. Now my question is why signature images are linked not attached. If Inline signature images are also treated in  same fashion as inline attachments, probably any mail client can support upload from local box. Is n't it?